# Read access violation writing location when trying to scanf_s into struct*?

Tags: c

I keep getting a read access violation whenever I try to run this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int i = 0;
struct basicValues{
    float rate, hoursWorked, grossPay, basePay, overtimePay, taxesPaid, netPay;
    char name[15];
};

void inputValues (struct basicValues *entered)
{   
    printf("Please enter your name, hourly pay, and hours worked this week: ");
    scanf_s("%s %f %f", entered->name, entered->rate, entered->hoursWorked);

}



void main()
{
    int i = 0;
    struct basicValues workers[5];

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        inputValues(&workers[i]);
        printf("%c %f %f", workers[i].name, workers[i].rate, workers[i].hoursWorked);
        system("pause");
    }

}
```

I think it has to do with my structure inputValues but I don't know what to change. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should [find a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), because you're not passing the correct arguments to `scanf`.

Comment: `scanf_s("%s %f %f", entered->name, entered->rate, entered->hoursWorked);` --> `scanf_s("%s %f %f", entered->name, sizeof(entered->name), &entered->rate, &entered->hoursWorked);`, `printf("%c %f %f", workers[i].name, workers[i].rate, workers[i].hoursWorked);` --> `printf("%s %f %f", workers[i].name, workers[i].rate, workers[i].hoursWorked);`

Comment: `scanf_s("%s"...` requires 2 following arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You should add & before primitive value types, as scanf expects the address of the variables. Like this

```
&entered->rate,   &entered->hoursWorked
```

Also use `%s`, not `%c` when printing a string